# Выполнить функции и получить ее ответ на старте приложения Flask

Tags: python, flask

Сразу по старту сервера Flask хочу чтобы выполнялась функция,и в переменную записывался ее результат.

```
def create_app():
    app = flask.Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(32)
    def first_to_do():
       bot_cookies = bot_init.get_cookies()
    first_to_do()
    return app
app = create_app()
```

По старту функция `first_to_do()` выполняется,но я не знаю как записать результат ее работы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этой цели служит [g-объект](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#storing-data)

```
from flask import g

def first_to_do():
    g.bot_cookies = bot_init.get_cookies()
```

Comment: тогда,забирать значение мне надо в виде: cookies = g.pop('bot_cookies', None) ?

Comment: @PythonNewbie зачем, просто `g.bot_cookies`

Comment: @andreymal Если написать такую строчку, то появляется ошибка AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'bot_cookies'